# How to create a new column with a conditional count in a groupby pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a DataFrame with a few features, something like this:

```
GEST    GERE    HOL
ONE1    1234    1
ONE1    6797    0
TWO2    6352    1
TWO2    5530    1
```

I want to group by `GEST` and create a new column `Count` if `HOL == 1` and assign it for `GEST`.

```
GEST    GERE    HOL    Count
ONE1    1234    1      1
ONE1    6797    0      1
TWO2    6352    1      2
TWO2    5530    1      2
```

Comment: `df['Count'] = df.groupby('GEST')['HOL'].transform('sum')`

Answer (score 4):

```
df['Count']=df.groupby('GEST')['HOL'].transform('sum')
```

**Output**

```
GEST    GERE    HOL    Count
ONE1    1234    1      1
ONE1    6797    0      1
TWO2    6352    1      2
TWO2    5530    1      2
```

If the input is a categorical value like 'Yes/No` as below

```
    GEST    GERE    HOL
0   ONE1    1234    Yes
1   ONE1    6797    No
2   TWO2    6352    Yes
3   TWO2    5530    Yes
```

You can use the code below to get the desired output

```
df['Count']=df.groupby('GEST')['HOL'].transform(lambda x : x.loc[x=='Yes'].count())
```

**Output**

```
    GEST    GERE    HOL     Count
0   ONE1    1234    Yes     1
1   ONE1    6797    No      1
2   TWO2    6352    Yes     2
3   TWO2    5530    Yes     2
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25291133)

Comment: @YasinPatel this is the answer to OP's question.

Comment: sorry about that, before it was just a single line without any details. My bad :(

Comment: How to revert it? so i can take back my review

Comment: I don't know. I would say, don't worry about it. May be a little careful in the future ;-)

Comment: Is a great answer, but what will happen if the feature "HOL" was categorical and not numerical?